# Location DOC TYPE and HTML tags in Magento

Tags: html, magento, tags

Can anyone tell me where to find The DOC TYPE or the HTML tag in Magento?

I can't seem to find it, the directory is somewhat too confusing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doctype is found in the page template files.
See:

- `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/1column.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/2column-left.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/2columns-right.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/3columns.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/empty.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/popup.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/page/print.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit many files to achieve this. Magento use 7 layout files (default). It may vary by theme. Just go to `app->design->frontend->default->YOUR_THEME->template->page` 
Here you can see the layout section files. Like,

```
1column.phtml, 2column-left.phtml, 2columns-right.phtml, 3columns.phtml, empty.phtml, popup.phtml, print.phtml
```

These are default magento layout section files.